# Android: Viewpager2 gets stuck half way

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2

When trying to swipe between any of my viewpager2 fragments, the view gets stuck at 75% of the transition.

### Picture

Swiping from first fragment to second fragment:

[image]

Swiping from second fragment to first fragment:

[image]

### Viewpager_Layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tl_on_boarding_item"
        style="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.EXAMPLE.ShopTablayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/unselected_shop_item_tab"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/selected_on_boarding_item_tab"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/primary"
        app:tabIndicatorFullWidth="false"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="8dp"
        app:tabMaxWidth="16dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Viewpager_Fragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class OnBoardingFragmentHolder @Inject constructor(
    private val onBoardingViewPagerAdapter: OnBoardingViewPagerAdapter,
    private val mediator: TabLayoutHelper,
) : InvisibleBottomNavFragment<FragmentOnBoardingHolderBinding>() {

    override val bindingInflater: (LayoutInflater) -> FragmentOnBoardingHolderBinding
        get() = FragmentOnBoardingHolderBinding::inflate

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initTablayout()
    }

    private fun initTablayout() {
        binding.viewPager.adapter = onBoardingViewPagerAdapter
        binding.viewPager.offscreenPageLimit = 2
        mediator.init(binding.tlOnBoardingItem, binding.viewPager)
    }

    override val onDestroyView: () -> Unit
        get() = {
            binding.viewPager.adapter = null
            mediator.onDestroyView()
        }
}
```

### InvisibleBottom Fragment

```
abstract class InvisibleBottomNavFragment<out T : ViewBinding> : BindingFragment<T>() {
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        postStickyEvent(MainActivityBusEventBottomNav(toBeClosed = true,
            fromClass = "InvisibleBottomNavFragment.kt"))
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        postStickyEvent(MainActivityBusEventBottomNav(toBeClosed = true,
            fromClass = "InvisibleBottomNavFragment.kt"))
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        postStickyEvent(MainActivityBusEventBottomNav(toBeClosed = true,
            fromClass = "InvisibleBottomNavFragment.kt"))
    }
}
```

### Viewpager

```
class OnBoardingViewPagerAdapter @Inject constructor(
    fragment: Fragment
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragment) {
    private companion object {
        private const val FRAGMENT_ITEM_COUNT = 3
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = FRAGMENT_ITEM_COUNT

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment = when (position) {
        0 -> OnBoardingFirstFragment()
        1 -> OnBoardingSecondFragment()
        2 -> OnBoardingThirdFragment()
        else -> throw IllegalStateException("$position can not be satisfied")
    }
}
```

What I find most weird is that when I fast swipe between the fragments (e.g not holding the mouse button up to the end and just swiping) everything works fine.

Comment: same here, did you found the problem?

Comment: @AliZarei Unfortunately not. The only "solution" I found was to disable swiping at all and add buttons to switch the pages..

Comment: Currently I've disabled user swipe but problem is still exist also with viewPager.setCurrentItem(index,false)

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399721/5033303